# How to add a button in a three js 3d .dae object

Tags: three.js, collada

I have imported a .dae file and added it to my scene. It is hosted here, as I couldn't host in codepen : http://freelancer.ueuo.com/threejs/ .

I want to add a button at the Front part of the stall, which says "CLICK ME" for example(designed by css) and then when I click the button I want a popup to appear. I know how to make the popup appear. But I have no idea how to add the button in the scene and use the raycaster to detect it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To add a button either you can define BoxGeometry(https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry) in front of your stall
or use some 3d objects through this link (https://www.turbosquid.com/) and place it at the front of your stall using

```
Object.position.set(x,y,z)
```

To make the raycaster be able to track your object you can initialize the same like

```
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera )
```

Basically, the origin of the raycaster will be your camera & the target will be mouse.

Now to listen to events on the 3d object you can use

```
intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( button3dObject )
```

if it intersects the button3dObject & click event is triggered then you can open your modal popup

Reference for how to use raycaster: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster

Comment: This is useful, but I want to design the button in css, and then add it to the scene!